# Legend position & bad x ticks scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I'm currently experimenting tikz-pgf, but facing some strong behaviour.

1. How is it possible to have only 1 legend for a groupplot?
2. Why is the scale 10^(-3) appearing below the first plot?

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },enlarge x limits=false,height=3cm, width=.8\textwidth,grid=major,scaled x ticks=base 10:3,legend cell align=left,legend pos=outer north east]
  \nextgroupplot
  \addplot[domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {0.8*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
  \legend{U [V],I [A]};
  \nextgroupplot[xlabel={t [s]}]
  \addplot[green,domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {0.8*1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
  \legend{S [VA]};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is an illustration of the output :
[image: illustration]

Comment: The `10^(-3)` is indeed a bug in the `groupplots` library. As a workaround, add `scaled x ticks=false` to the first `\nextgroupplot` options.

Comment: @Jake's comment is correct. And the request to get just one legend should probably become a feature request; the groupplots lib currently only supports separate legends per plot.

Comment: Yep i adopted Jake's fix. the fact of having only one legend is purely aesthetic..

Comment: @Jake Would you write an answer or should ask for closing it as a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To create a common legend, add all legend entries (using `\addlegendimage`) in one of the `\nextgroupplot`s. To place it at an arbitrary position (e.g., centered horizontally or verticallr, which is IMHO the best option for a common legend), use `legend to name` and then create a node with a reference.
2. To remove the ·10<sup>-3</sup> mark, you can add `xtick scale label code/.code={}` option to the `\nextgroupplot` definition.

Please find attached an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    }, enlarge x limits=false, height=3cm, width=.8\textwidth, grid=major,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3, legend cell align=left]
  \nextgroupplot[xtick scale label code/.code={}, legend to name=fig:my plots:grouplegend]
  \addplot[domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {0.8*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
  \addlegendimage{green, line legend}
  \legend{U [V],I [A],S [VA]}
  \nextgroupplot[xlabel={t [s]}]
  \addplot[green,domain=0:0.05,samples=200]
    {0.8*1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
\end{groupplot}
\node [right] at ($(my plots c1r1.east)!.5!(my plots c1r2.east)$)
    {\ref{fig:my plots:grouplegend}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

If I may suggest something, it may be more readable if you scale the x ticks but inform the reader about it by prefixing the unit. You can do it by adding `scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1*1000}}`. In that case, no buggy ·10<sup>-3</sup> marks appear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group name=my plots 2,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    }, enlarge x limits=false, height=3cm, width=.8\textwidth, grid=major,
    scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1*1000}}, legend cell align=left]
  \nextgroupplot[legend to name=fig:my plots 2:grouplegend]
  \addplot[domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:0.05,samples=200] {0.8*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
  \addlegendimage{green, line legend}
  \legend{U [V],I [A],S [VA]}
  \nextgroupplot[xlabel={t [ms]}]
  \addplot[green,domain=0:0.05,samples=200]
    {0.8*1.2*sin(2*pi*50*\x r)*sin(2*pi*50*(\x r-0.25))};
\end{groupplot}
\node [right] at ($(my plots 2 c1r1.east)!.5!(my plots 2 c1r2.east)$)
    {\ref{fig:my plots 2:grouplegend}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]