# Persistent "hanging" tick label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have sort of a strange problem. I produced a 3x2 plot array in Matlab, and removed all of the y-axis tick labels. The relevant code (for the problematic plot) is below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
scaled y ticks = true,
xmin=0,
xmax=50,
xtick={ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=15e6,
ytick={0,5e6,10e6,15e6},
yticklabels={,,,},
name=plot1,
at=(plot3.above north west),
anchor=below south west
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 102360.942462359\\
2 85927.6966525591\\
3 2845564.93058913\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

The other plots are similar, but without this problem. The resulting figure is

[image]

There's that orphaned tick label in the top left corner, and I don't know why it's there or how to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [remove the axis multiplier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier), set `scaled y ticks=false`. To keep the tick marks but not print any labels, set `yticklabels={}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
scaled y ticks = true,
xmin=0,
xmax=50,
xtick={ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=15e6,
ytick={0,5e6,10e6,15e6},
scaled y ticks=false,
yticklabel=\relax,
anchor=below south west
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 102360.942462359\\
2 85927.6966525591\\
3 2845564.93058913\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought this was that bug about the scale axis key

Comment: @percusse: You were probably thinking of [Legend position & bad x ticks scale](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100685/legend-position-bad-x-ticks-scale)?